# UserProfile picture asking Credentials to load?

Tags: development, user-profile, user-profile-property

I have tried to get the User Profile picture from server side

```
public void getUserProfilePictureUrl(SPUser currentUser)
{
    try
    {
        string pictureURL = string.Empty;
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite mySitesCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb myweb = mySitesCollection.OpenWeb())
                {
                    string currentUserlogin = currentUser.LoginName;
                    //Get the user profile manager
                    SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(mySitesCollection);
                    UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
                    UserProfile currentProfile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(currentUserlogin);
                    mysiteURL = currentProfile.PersonalUrl.AbsoluteUri;
                    //PicutreURL - property name
                    ProfileValueCollectionBase profileValueCollection = currentProfile.GetProfileValueCollection("PictureURL");
                    //Only display something if the user has set their picture.
                    if ((profileValueCollection != null) && (profileValueCollection.Value != null))
                    {
                        //There is a picture so display it
                        profilePictureURL = profileValueCollection.Value.ToString() ;
                        Uri urlCheck = new Uri(profilePictureURL);
                        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlCheck);
                        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
                        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                        try
                        {
                            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            profilePictureURL = "/_layouts/15/images/PersonPlaceholder.42x42x32.png";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //no image found url
                        profilePictureURL = "/_layouts/15/images/PersonPlaceholder.42x42x32.png";
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        profilePictureURL = "/_layouts/15/images/PersonPlaceholder.42x42x32.png";
    }

}
```

It's asking credentials to load the picture, using CSOM we can solve this by passing the account name, I am not sure about this. Please suggest me some idea to solve this issue.

Comment: to get user photo you can try this /_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=userName.onmicrosoft.com  reference: https://mysharepointlearnings.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/user-profile-picture-in-sp-hosted-app/

Comment: Your RWEP line is probably the issue. Does your Web App account have access to the User Profile Service?

Comment: Ya its separate web application and I have access to the user profile service